# How to specify javascript method on menu item click in managed bean?

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces :4

I need to create a Programmatic Menu & specify a javascript method which would be called on click of the menu item.

I am unable to understand how to specify the javascript method to be called on menu item click in the managed bean.

Only the client side method needs to be called. Server side method is not required to be called.

```
@ManagedBean
public class MenuView {

    private MenuModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        //First submenu
        DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");

        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("ABC");
        item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
        firstSubmenu.addElement(item);


...
        model.addElement(firstSubmenu);
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use : `item.setOnclick(String click)`

Check out the API : http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/model/menu/DefaultMenuItem.html#setOnclick(java.lang.String)